# Installing jexcelapi

Tags: java, jexcelapi

how do you use the third party libraries?

I have downloaded it, but am unsure what to do with it, do i place it in my eclipse project folder etc?

I did look on the website but to no avail

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to install a Java JAR file. Instead you set the JAR in the classpath.

See [Setting Eclipse Classpath](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the jar in your project classpath. 
After importing you can use the libraries and the API's exposed to you by importing the class